# SELECT to sum the time between events the request is sent/received in a tree structure and calculating the average time for each request at the root

Tags: sql, postgresql

Write postgresql SELECT-expression to find average network latency for each request processed by the root host in a tree network of hosts, based on event data stored in a single database.
Calculate average network delay by finding the sum of datetime differences between RequestSent/RequestReceived and ResponseSent/ResponseReceived events. Calculate the average query execution time for all requests to the root host.

[image: Screen of test data for better understanding]
Exported sql file https://dropmefiles.com/Y5dXS

There are two root queries. Let's write down the times that have passed between sending the request/response and receiving it.

```
Request with id 0:
balancer.test -> backend1 – 50ms (from 0.100s to 0.150s)
balancer.test -> backend2 – 99ms (from 0.101s to 0.200s)
backend1 -> backend3 – 45ms (from 0.155s to 0.200s)
backend2 -> balancer.test – 40ms (from 0.210s to 0.250s)
backend3 -> backend1 – 40ms (from 0.220s to 0.260s)
backend1 -> balancer.test – 10ms (from 0.300s to 0.310s)
```

The sum is 284ms

```
Request with id 4:
balancer.test -> backend1 – 5ms (from 0.505s to 0.510s)
backend1 -> balancer.test – 10ms (from 0.700s to 0.710s)
```

The sum is 15ms

So, the answer is ( 284 + 15) ∕ 2 = 149.5.

I tried to implement this non-recursive query, but gives an incorrect negative result. I think we need recursion here, but I've no idea how to implement this. Can you help me?

```
WITH event_pairs AS (
    SELECT
        t1.request_id,
        t1.datetime AS sent_time,
        MIN(t2.datetime) AS received_time
    FROM
        requests t1
        JOIN requests t2 ON t1.request_id = t2.parent_request_id
    WHERE
        (t1.type = 'RequestSent' AND t2.type = 'RequestReceived')
        OR (t1.type = 'ResponseSent' AND t2.type = 'ResponseReceived')
    GROUP BY
        t1.request_id,
        t1.datetime
),
request_latency AS (
    SELECT
        request_id,
        SUM((received_time - sent_time) * 1000) AS latency
    FROM
        event_pairs
    GROUP BY
        request_id
),
root_requests AS (
    SELECT
        request_id
    FROM
        requests
    WHERE
        parent_request_id IS NULL
        AND type = 'RequestReceived'
)
SELECT
    AVG(latency) AS average_latency
FROM
    request_latency
    JOIN root_requests USING (request_id);
```

Comment: Isn't "average network delay" the mean time spent on network hops? In other words, simply `avg(t_recv - t_sent)`? In your example, instead of `(284 + 15) / 2`, I would instead say `(284 + 15) / (6 + 2): 37.375ms`. If so, that's a simple join query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! We need to count the average delay on each of the root requests. Child queries are not counted as separate, so we divide by two.

Comment: @PierreD
But your task is very similar. Could you show this join query pls?

Comment: I didn't have a chance to get back to this until now, but it looks like you've got an answer that works for your case. I was thinking of a recursive CTE to count only the completed requests (i.e. all those that start with `parent=NULL` and, after however many subqueries, come back to self with a response. This would avoid counting "parasite rows" (incomplete requests, other log entries) if there are any. LMK if that is needed, otherwise I'll move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example counts total time of path and average time.
You don't need recursive query

```
    WITH trips as(
    select t1.host as sender,t1.datetime senttime
       ,t2.host as reciever,t2.datetime recievetime
       ,t2.datetime-t1.datetime as delt
    from requests t1
    inner join requests t2 on 
           (t1.type = 'RequestSent' AND t2.type = 'RequestReceived'
            and t1.data=t2.host and t2.parent_request_id=t1.request_id)
        OR (t1.type = 'ResponseSent' AND t2.type = 'ResponseReceived'
            and t2.data=t1.host and t1.parent_request_id=t2.request_id)  
    )
   select 
        sum(recievetime-senttime) as totTime
       ,(select count(distinct request_id) 
          from (select request_id from requests where parent_request_id is null) x
        ) cnt
       ,sum(recievetime-senttime) /
        (select count(distinct request_id) 
        from (select request_id from requests where parent_request_id is null) x
        ) avgtime
    from trips
```

Root requests - requests with no parent request.

Result table

| tottime | cnt | avgtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.29900000000000004 | 2 | 0.14950000000000002 |

All paths

| sender | senttime | reciever | recievetime | delt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| balanser.test | 0.1 | backend1 | 0.15 | 0.04999999999999999 |
| balanser.test | 0.101 | backend2 | 0.2 | 0.099 |
| backend1 | 0.155 | backend3 | 0.2 | 0.04500000000000001 |
| backend2 | 0.21 | balancer.test | 0.25 | 0.04000000000000001 |
| backend3 | 0.22 | backend1 | 0.26 | 0.04000000000000001 |
| backend1 | 0.3 | balanser.test | 0.31 | 0.010000000000000009 |
| balanser.test | 0.505 | `backend1` | 0.51 | 0.0050000000000000044 |
| `backend1` | 0.7 | balanser.test | 0.71 | 0.010000000000000009 |

If you will count time for every root request, recursive query is helpfull.